# My computer screen turned black does not change

Tags: windows-10, display

So I was on my laptop computer and, out of nowhere, the screen of my computer turned black and now it displays nothing more. I turned of and on again and it was still black. I decided to connect my PC to a second display and I noticed that it is functional and I can use the computer through this display. What can I do to solve this?

PS: I have investigated in some online articles, but none of them offer a solution to my problem, since it is always different, like for example, the screen has a cursor (mine does not) or by clicking CTRL+ALT+DELETE it appears the Task Manager (in mine it only appears in the second display).

PS: I have windows 10 64 bits

If I have any information missing please tell!

Comment: Seems your monitor has died or has problem. Have you tried connecting your monitor to another computer?

Comment: I am sorry if i did not make my self clear, but the monitor that stopped working is from builtin my laptop. I do not know if it is possible to connect it to another computer.

Comment: nope it's not possible. I guess you should bring it to a shop. It mau be costly to repair the monitor tho.

Comment: Ok it is good to know, I have insurance since I do not trust my colleagues. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you can see the initial boot screen when you turn on your computer, but it goes blank once Windows starts to load, then you know it’s an issue with Windows.

If Windows is corrupt, then your only option is to boot into safe mode and then try to repair Windows.

I would try system restore or automatic repair first and if neither of those work, then try resetting your PC. Resetting your PC will preserve all your programs and data, but reinstall the Windows system files.

In addition your hardware may have got some issue or display is dead. Visit a computer repair shop.

Comment: The screen simply goes black it shows nothing else

Comment: You got problem with your hardware I guess. Visit repair shop.